# Get more info about uncaughtException in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do i get more info on events like `unhandledError` or `unhandledRejection` in nodeJs?

For example, in browser, i can simply add this listener:

```
window.onerror = function(message, page, lineno, colno, error) {

};
```

Which gives me error name, stack, type and even location.

But in nodeJs, i see only the message, and nothing else:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  console.log('catched!', err);
});
```

How do i get more info about it? full stack trace, type of error separately from it's message etc? Like i did in browser.

Comment: Does `err` not have a `.stack` property?

Comment: It does, thank you. Where can i find list of all properties? this docs are kind of confusing: https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html and looping through `err` doesn't work

Comment: This is a pretty good reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Comment: Be aware though that when you receive an `uncaughtException`, the stack associated with the `Error` object typically won't have anything useful in it due to the async nature of node.